# QLabel show image slowly

Tags: image, qt

I develop a image browser to show image series with QSlider. I connncet valueChanged(int) of QSlider to a self-defined function:

```
QObject::connect(ui.imgIndexSlider, SIGNAL(valueChanged(int)), this,SLOT(onimgIndexSliderValueChanged(int)));
```

when I drag the slider, the image that QLabel shows will changed by the QSlider value.It works.But there is a problem that if you drag fast,the Application will not run acceptably.
Could you tell me how to slove this problem.
Thank you very much.

[image: the UI of my appliction]

Comment: Can you show a screenshot of your application so that we can understand what you are doing?

Comment: this is a screenshot fo my appliction:)

Answer (score 0):

It is not clear much from your question, but I am assuming that you are showing images like a slideshow using the slider. When you slide it fast your application is getting choked i.e. freezes?
Qt is rendering the image in your GUI thread.
If the images are all high resolution then it will take much more time in rendering each image.
When you slide faster than Qt can render a single image you *will* experience problems.
So here is what I would ideally do if I were in your place:

1. Implement a custom algorithm which will read the image file and
   create a preview image of much smaller size. Since you are only
   generating a pixmap in memory, you can do this by multi threading.
   You can do this when your application is launched.
2. Show all the preview's as scrollable tiles on left pane similar to
   Powerpoint. You can reduce some coding here by letting Qt render
   these preview's by using `QLabel`.
3. Have a central widget which occupies the major chunk of the window
   which will render the images using your custom algorithm. Your
   algorithm will be such that it will read the actual image if the
   slider is not running. If slider is running *fast enough* then you simply need to
   scale your preview images and display in the widget.

Feel free to ask questions if you find anything difficult to understand. :)